# Perform multiple clicks as long as user is hovering over an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery. What it does is that once you hover over the next or previous arrows, it clicks on them, making the slider move. I need to modify this code, so it keeps clicking as long as you are hovering, right now, it only does it once.

```
$( "#slider .next, #slider .prev" ).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).click();
    }, 
    function() {}
);
```

The slider uses a jQuery plugin called [Tiny Carousel](http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/)

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what the negative votes are for?

Comment: Do you need to click them? Could you not call the code that happens on `click` instead? That might be easier to do

Comment: @amura.cxg I can try and find the code attached to those arrows, but even then, it would still click once instead of repeating the clicks.

Comment: Check lines 143 - 153 on the non-minified version. This is where the events happen. What you're attempting to do with fake clicks is probably not the best idea.

Comment: you can use the interval option with the methods start() and stop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will trigger a click on the elements every second:

```
var clr;
$(".next, .prev").hover(function (e) {
    clr = setInterval(function () {
        $(e.target).click();
    }, 1000)
}, function () {
    clearInterval(clr);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/acaeh614/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var handle=null;
$( "#slider .next, #slider .prev" ).hover(
function() {      
  var self=$(this);
if(handle!=null)
clearInterval(handle);

handle = setInterval(function(){
    $(this).click();
   },100);

},   
 function() {}
);
```